# Save output of $_SERVER to file

Tags: php

I use this :

```
<?php
foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value){
echo "<b>$key:</b> $value<br>\n";
}

 ?>
```

Which outputs in browser. Is there anyway to redirect output to file and hide it from the browser page ?

Comment: Have you searched for 'php write file'?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php in general. There is a search form there as well. You really need to learn to use search before being lazy and have other people answer basic questions like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest something like:

```
<?php
foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value)
{
  file_put_contents('the_file.txt', "<b>$key:</b> $value<br>\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

Make sure that `the_file.txt` has write permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of echoing build an output to put in your file:

```
<?php
$in='';
foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value){
    $in .= $key.' - '.$value.PHP_EOL;
}
//save it
file_put_contents('_SERVER.txt', $in);
?>
```

Also, Your not going to want to add any html tags.

Answer (score 1):

To write a file you would want to use [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/file_put_contents). To generate a (human) readable representation of the contents of `$_SERVER` you should look into [print_r()](http://php.net/print_r) or [var_export()](http://php.net/var_export).

```
file_put_contents("/tmp/exported-server.txt", print_r($_SERVER, true));
```

using `$s = print_r($_SERVER)`, `$s = var_export($_SERVER)` or even `ob_start(); var_dump($_SERVER); $s = ob_get_clean();` makes sure you get a proper visualization of any value type. Your approach only works well for strings and numbers, but fails for arrays, objects, …